# Function sscanf not respecting width field

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I'm trying to parse a mac address using `sscanf`.  Here's my attempt:

```
uint8_t mac[6];

//string version of mac address stored in s
if(strlen(s) == 17 && sscanf(s, 
    "%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx", 
    &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5]) == 6)
{ /*the mac address was parsed correctly*/ }
```

This works for the usual case of something like `00:00:00:00:00:00`, but it parses the address `00:00:00:00:0:123` as `00:00:00:00:00:12`.

Can `sscanf` handle this case, or will I have to manually parse the string?

Edit: The format should be exactly "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx".  If a byte can fit in just one character, it must be written with a leading zero.

Comment: Since you specify 2 characters per component, it scans at most 2 per component.  What do you expect it to do on an input with more characters?

Comment: I wanted it to read exactly 2 characters, with leading 0's if necessary.

Comment: If you want it to read up to two characters, then wouldn't `00:00:00:00:0:123` be incorrect? Indeed, I know right away that's an incorrect MAC address.

Comment: As you now found out, `scanf` (and family) are not really good for parsing and validating strings, just for extracting values from strings. You need to come up with another method of parsing and validating the string, for example a `strtok` loop with `strtoul` to parse and check the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field width given in `scanf` formats is the *maximum* field width -- there's no way to specify a minimum field width (so the minimum is always 1).  So if you want to read a fixed width field and reject shorter fields, you'll need to check all the field separators directly.  If you also want to reject strings with whitespace (`scanf` ignores whitespace on all conversion types other than `c`, `n` and `[`), you'll need to use something else.

```
int check_mac(const char *s, uint8_t *mac) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++, s += 3) {
        if (!isxdigit(s[0]) || !isxdigit(s[1]) || s[2] != ":::::"[i])
            return -1;
        sscanf(s, "%hhx", &mac[i]); }
    return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would feel much better about using [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

```
unsigned char mac[6];
const char * s = "00:00:00:00:0:12";
const char * delims = ":";

char temp[100];
strcpy(temp, s);

char * str = strtok(temp, delims);
int i = 0;
do
{
    if (sscanf(str, "%hhx", &mac[i++]) < 1)
        break;
} while ((i < 6) && ((str = strtok(NULL, delims)) != NULL));
```

Comment: hope nobody types an extra `:`

Comment: `sscanf` would catch it, but you make a good point if someone entered an extra `:00` for example. I wrote this late last night--Edited to fix.

Comment: This does not appear to properly detect failure of `"0:00:00:00:0:12"` per OP's "If a byte can fit in just one character, it must be written with a leading zero."

Comment: I took that to mean it's a requirement of the input, that is, an assumption we can make about the input. I did not take that to mean the code must enforce that rule, so since it's convenient not to, I didn't.